# Suppress poem line numeration only in selected environments

Tags: environments, verse

I would like to drop the poem line numeration for only one poem, thus forcing it to behave differently from the general setting defined for the `verse` environment of my document.

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

% Global setting
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemlines{2}


\poemtitle{Garden}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{No Poem Lines for this enviroment!}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `\poemlines` to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\begin{document}

% Global setting
\verselinenumbersleft
\setlength{\vrightskip}{-3em}
\poemlines{2}


\poemtitle{Garden}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{No Poem Lines for this enviroment!}
\poemlines{0}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}

\poemtitle{Garden}
\poemlines{2}
\begin{verse}
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
I used to love my garden \\
But now my love is dead \\
For I found a bachelor's button \\
In black-eyed Susan's bed.\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So do I need to make sure I then reset `\poemlines{}` to the original value?

Comment: @Francesco Yes.